# "Missing dependency. This algorithm cannot be run" with QGIS + GRASS in Windows 7?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, installation, error, windows

Windows 7, OsGeo4W pack installed including QGIS 2.4.0 and GRASS.

In QGIS when I try to execute a GRASS geoprocessing algorithm I get this popup:

> Missing dependency. This algorithm cannot be run :-( 
>   This algorithm requires GRASS GIS 7 to be run. Unfortunately, it seems that GRASS GIS 7 is not installed in your system, or it is not correctly configured to be used from QGIS
>   Click here to know more about how to install and configure GRASS GIS 7 to be used with QGIS

The link doesn't help. I get the same message at my computer at work with QGIS 2.2.0

The GRASS plugins are activated under geoprocessing settings.

Do I need to configure something?

[image]

When I run MSYS I get this:

[image]

Comment: Can you run GRASS independently? Also note that QGis 2.4 just been released yesterday and there might be initial issues

Comment: What about if you try SAGA tools? I have posted on http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9671 - missing dependency when using Windows network user account. If I use local account all works fine.

Comment: Curlew: I cant run GRASS independently, it goes BEEP and i see a startup popup for 0,5 s.

Miro: When i try SAGA from qgis i get the same error "Missing depen...."

Comment: your path Bj"rn or Björn is not correct (without space nor accent)

Comment: Gene: i know, how do i change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSYS stumbles upon the non-ACII characters of your Windows user name. Maybe GRASS fails on that too.

Try with a new user name without non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Processing Toolbox:

[image]

There are algoritithms for GRASS GIS 6.x (GRASS commands) and GRASS GIS 7 (GRASS GIS 7 commands).

Have you configured the path of GRASS 7 ([Configuring external applications](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html)) ?

Comment: I dont know, have i? Look at screenshot above. Left one is GRASS command line. GRASS gui wont start