# QGIS 2.8 problem accessing GRASS commands

Tags: grass-gis, lidar, windows-7, qgis-2.8

QGIS 2.8.1 Win7 64 bit installed with osgeo4w-setup.

I’m trying to run GRASS commands on a LIDAR raster layer but I get the following message:

> Missing dependency.... GRASS not installed in your system` message each time.

GRASS appears in the processing tools pane and the “Processing options” for GRASS shows the Msys and GRASS folders locations correctly (which was a problem for a similar questioner). I note that GRASS has been 7.0 stable since mid February but osgeo4w-setup only shows GRASS 6. All manuals refer to a ‘GRASS plugin’ but none seem to be listed now.

Is there 'best-practice' way of installing GRASS functionality in QGIS 2.8 on Windows7 64 bit?

As a supplementary question is it possible to install a GRASS add-on that is not part of the core GRASS setup (I need [r.skyview](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/r.skyview.html) for LIDAR visualisation of archaeological features)?

Comment: May be this answer will help you http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103565/missing-dependency-this-algorithm-cannot-be-run-qgis-grass-windows-7

Comment: You need to switch on GRASS GIS 7 support under "Advanced Interface" (see here for a screenshot: http://adhoc.osgeo.osuosl.org/livedvd/docs/en/quickstart/qgis_quickstart.html#using-the-processing-toolbox)

Comment: There is no evidence to assume that the issue in this ticket has to do with non-ascii characters in the path; Hence this is not a duplicate.